# value 'snake' doesn't support membership test python or python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
from random import randint
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()

if snake.xcor and snake.ycor == apple.xcor and apple.ycor:                             
    food = []
    Main_Score += 1
    pen.write("score:{}".format(Main_Score), align="center", font=("courier", 24, "normal"))
    while food == []:
        food = [randint(1, 18), randint(1, 58)]      
        if food in snake: food == []
    wn.addch(food[0], food[1], '*')
```

I have looked at some other questions and the  line `if food in snake: food == []` won't work because of value 'snake' doesn't support membership test

Comment: what is `snake` ? I don't see where you create it. And what do you try to do with `food in snake` ? maybe you should compare `food == [snake.xcor(), snake.ycor()]` or `food == snake.pos()`. BTW: you forgot `()` in `xcor()` and `ycor()`

Comment: Sorry for not adding this detail in but im creating snake food is the food that the snake eats ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare positions then you should use

```
food == snake.pos()
```

---

Similar

```
snake.pos() == apple.pos()
```

or

```
(snake.xcor(), snake.ycor()) == (apple.xcor(), apple.ycor())
```

Your line

```
if snake.xcor and snake.ycor == apple.xcor and apple.ycor:
```

is wrong because you forgot `()` in `xcor()`, `ycor()` and becaue it means

```
if (snake.xcor) and (snake.ycor == apple.xcor) and (apple.ycor):
```

so `and` doesn't work as you expect.

---

Instead of

```
while food == []:
```

you can write

```
while not food:
```